# How to set cutoff for AWS account billing?

Tags: amazon-web-services

In the billing dashboard I have configured alerts to get notified when the cost reaches at a certain amount.

Along with alert I would also like to setup a cutoff so that the cost never goes beyond a certain amount. Where can I do this setting?

Comment: You can try looking into budget actions: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws-cost-management/get-started-with-aws-budgets-actions/ - "There are three action types: Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies, Service Control policies (SCPs), or target running instances (EC2 or RDS). Actions can be configured for actual (after they’ve occurred) or for forecasted (before they occur) budgeted amounts."

Answer (score 1):

You cannot stop from being billed within AWS by selecting a setting, the alert will simply notify you that you have surpassed a threshold.

If you wanted to prevent the billing you should have the alert trigger a Lambda function, this you would have to be developed to terminate resources in your account. Otherwise you will need to manually go through your AWS account and manually delete resources.

A good tip would be to set the threshold lower than your budget so that you can be notified ahead of time and react before it exceeds this.